# Overloading methods by return type in java

Tags: java

Can I collapse those two "getFields" methods into one  using generics (the second method is intended to package private access) or should I rename the second one into something ugly like "getFieldPackagePrivate"?

```
public interface IField {

}


class Field implements IField { // package private class

}


  public class IForm {


     public List<IField> getFields();

  }



public class Form {
  private List<Field> fields;


  public List<IField> getFields() {
    return this.fields;

  }

  List<Field> getFields() { // package visible
    return this.fields;

  }

}
```

the basic usage would be like this

```
// by interfece - from client code

  IForm form;
  List<IField> list = form.getFields();

// by class - from other classes in the same package
  Form form2;
  List<Field> list2 = forms2.getFields();
```

The idea is to have a clean, save  interface for an outside world and a convenient access (without downcasts) from package visible implementation clacces. My Field Class has a few  methods that I don't want do be seen by a client but need to invoke from other classes in the same packege (like for example setLabel etc.)

Comment: @lbownik: I've changed the title to talk about overloading rather than overriding, because that's what you're really interested in as far as I can tell. Let me know if this isn't correct.

Comment: hm. isn't covariance allowed? maybe he could return a base from the interface which would contain the List<IField> , and a derived from the implementation which would contain the List<Field> ?

Answer (score 3):

You can write (as per my answer to your previous question):

```
public List<? extends IField> getFields()
```

but you can't overload by return type, and you can't expose a package-private type in a public method.

EDIT: With the change of the question, the answer is a simple "no". You'll have to rename your other method.

Comment: I reedited it a little to make my intenntion clearer - please look agani. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't have polymorphism based on return type in Java.

Answer (score 0):

After I experimented a little I found a solution based on Jon Skeet's answer

The code looks like this.

```
public interface IField {

}


class Field implements IField { // package private class

}


  public class IForm {


     public List<? extends IField> getFields();

  }



public class Form {
  private List<Field> fields;


  List<? extends Field> getFields() { // package visible - please note "extends Field" not "extends IField"
    return this.fields;

  }

}
```

now the dote below works

```
  IForm form;
  List<IField> list = form.getFields();

// by class - from other classes in the same package
  Form form2;
  List<Field> list2 = forms2.getFields();
```

Comment: yes this is essentially covariance i guess :) anyway, doesn't this violate substitution principle? the getFields method in Form would still have to be public.

Comment: Yes, but if I make the Form class package private and use a factory class with a method that returns IFrom (I actually use it ) then everything should be ok. :]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with bytecode manipulation, check this article:
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/07/31/return-type-based-method-overloading.html